# E-mail PHPMailer para Hotmail

Tags: php, formulário, phpmailer

Não estou conseguindo enviar um e-mail do formulário para meu e-mail Hotmail. Abaixo seguem os códigos:

Formulário com os dados que serão enviados.

```
<form id="form-contato" method="post" action="email.php">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
            </div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <textarea name="message" id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row 200%">
            <div class="12u">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar mensagem"/></li>
                    <li><input type="reset" value="Limpar campos" class="alt" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Classe email.php para capturar os dados do formulário e enviar o e-mail:

```
<?php 

  require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->SMTPDebug=1;
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->CharSet = "utf8";
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = 'meuemail@hotmail.com';
  $mail->Password = 'minhasenha';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Port = 465; 
  $mail->FromName = "De";
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->addAddress($_POST['email'],$_POST['nome']);
  $mail->Subject = $_POST['assunto'];
  $mail->Body =$_POST['mensagem'];

  if(!$mail->Send()){       
      echo 'Erro ao enviar e-mail: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
  }else{
      echo 'E-mail enviado';
  }
```

Erro retornado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não chega nem na caixa de spam?

Comment: não chega nem no spam

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss postei a foto do erro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A porta utilizada pelo hotmail](https://answers.microsoft.com/pt-br/outlook_com/forum/osettings-oemailset/qual-o-smtp-do-hotmail/3e429e8f-5133-432a-a90f-220ea9f3fe0d) é a porta 587, então:

```
$mail->Port = 587;
```

O que pode ser tentado além de mudar a porta, é trocar o SMTPSecure , já que o [Hotmail utiliza StartTLS](https://together.jolla.com/question/59505/solvedhow-to-setup-outgoing-smtp-server-for-hotmail-on-jolla/), então:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Confira nas configurações do hotmail se ele permite que um cliente SMTP externo faça a conexão.

Comment: O seguinte erro é retornado pra mim:2017-02-12 22:56:49 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2017-02-12 22:56:49 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Erro ao enviar e-mail: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting